# Does Whimsyshire drop better loot than other areas?

Tags: diablo-iii

I like to put on Magic-Find gear and go farm for good items, however I've been feeling a bit disheartened lately because of the hours spent re-running acts with over 200% magic find, and only finding yellows that are not even worth putting on the AH.

I haven't tried Whimsyshire yet though, and have been thinking about farming the items to go there.

Does Whimsyshire provide better loot quality than re-running through the acts? Or better opportunies for loot, such as more champion groups in a smaller area?

Comment: I think you should specify on which difficulty, because its a little bit different when you just hit 60 and try to farm Inferno Whimsyshire but need about 2h and tons of deaths, rather then running in Hell and 2 shot everything.

Comment: @Nappy The question is about loot drop quality/chance, not ease/difficulty of clearing the area :) The difficulty level should not matter. I'll make some slight edits to the question to try and clarify that

Comment: I doubt loot quality is higher than Act IV, and the drops seem to be slightly better. Plus, it's a fairly easy farm spot, rather than finding a specific quest to run through

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [developer AMAA](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6317360/6317360)  on reddit:

> d3db: With the drop rates released in the 1.0.3 preview, is Whimsyshire considered part of Act I or Act III/IV?
>
> Andrew Chambers: We dont really consider the Whimsy-ical Shire to be part of the story proper, but the new drop rates will affect it. Specifically, the monsters in hell are considered act IV hell monsters, and the monsters in Inferno are Act III/IV Inferno monsters.

Answer (score 4):

From my experience doing nightmare and hell Whimsyshire a few times now, I find that the drop quality is always the equivilant of the next Act up. So Normal Whimsyshire is the equivilant of Act I nightmare drops. I have found higher level gems than I can find in all of the difficulty in that difficulties Whimsyshire.

Thus, Inferno Whimsyshire drops should equal Act I of what we will call *Super Inferno*.

Not to mention I have found very few Legendary items (4 to be exact) and 3 of them were found in Whimsyshire. They weren't the best, but they each netted be a decent amount on the AH.

Also, those cute little clouds are everywhere, and with decent magic find yield a lot of oppourtunities to find something awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Okay clear some stuff up I have seen 5 different boss types(purple named)There is one for each type of creature and then there is Team Unicorn which is 4 mini named ponies that will wreck your world if you are not geared right and each one drops loot blue-legendary.

next hit the Desicrated Crypts area and get your valor buff up takes a few mins if geared correctly and you have a chance at level 31-47 rares legendaries.

Depending on set up and desire I make a lot more in whimsy then farming act 4 hell for sure however in hell mode you can get some real nasty named combos invunrable mortar illusionist is just so wrong when it happens.

As for drops I get anywhere from lvl 51-59 items and avg 8 rares per run and about 50 blues.

Gold is about 120k a hour.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Whimsyshire expect items that are available in act 4 final quest for that difficulty. If you do inferno I would suggest being a friend or 3 and sticking together.

As for the magic find it helps but not enough. Unless you hit like 300 or more don't expect great things.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say this, and I don't have any math or official posts to back it up, but everytime I go to Whimsyshire I need to return to town at least once in the middle of it to sell off all my items, and that is only picking up blue or better items. Therefore it **SEEMS** that there are more opportunities for better loot in Whimsyshire than other places.

Each time I make the run I usually get several yellows, and blues seems to drop off of everything.

I don't know if the mobs have an increased chance to drop magic items while in there, or that there are simply so many "chests" to interact with, or even that the mobs are more closely grouped together, but my pockets are always stuffed whenever I leave that place.

Comment: If you even consider it worth mentioning you're "only picking up blue or better", it seems likey you're not answering the question here, which is obviously about farming for inferno level gear. Just because something's "yellow" it's not good, and the question clearly refers to those as "not worth AHing".

Comment: @Desiato - I think you're missing the point of the answer then. If I am accumulating more magic and rare items in a Whimsy run than I am in an Act IV run, then there is some credence to saying that Whimsyshire is a better place to farm rare items, therefore as asked by Rachel... it provided a better opportunity. This question is not going to have a definitive answer, as no Blue post is ever going to say "Whimsyshire is better for phat lewtz"

Answer (score 0):

Blue posts have even mentioned that whimsyshire is not meant to give you the best opportunity at great gear. It was made more for fun and not for gear unlike the d2 cow level which had several of the best drops ingame.