# Did the loot table of Whimsyshire on Hell changed post-Patch 1.0.3?

Tags: diablo-iii

From [the official patch notes](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5238315/Patch_103_Now_Live-20_06_2012):

> - High-end items (items level 61-63) will now drop in all Acts of Inferno and Acts III and IV of Hell 
>     The new approximate drop rates are as follows:
>
>   - Hell - Act III and Act IV
>
>     - iLvl 61: 9%
>     - iLvl 62: 1.9%
>     - iLvl 63: 0%
>   - [...]

I'd like to know if this also affects Whimsyshire: Do mobs there (on Hell difficulty) also drop ilvl 61/62 now?

I think so because mobs in Whimsyshire usually seem to drop items of the same quality as Act IV of the chosen difficulty. Otherwise, the entrance to the secret level is located in Act I which isn't listed there.

Sadly I can't find this out myself as I only got the Staff of Herding for Normal difficulty till now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Whimsyshire drop better loot than other areas?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70921/does-whimsyshire-drop-better-loot-than-other-areas)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Whimsyshire drops the same loot as act 4 of the same difficulty that you're on (except for inferno which drops loot of the same quality as acts 3 and 4, which have the same drop rates).

This means that Hell Whimsyshire will drop iLvl 61 and 62 items at the same rate as Act 3/4 will.

Comment: It is also worth noting that while the loot table has been adjusted to match the loot buff, that the 'Magic Find RE: Containers' nerf was probably specifically at Whimsyshire - so lower quality loot will drop from Happy Clouds and Pot O' Golds... ["Magic Find will no longer be considered when looting objects in the environment such as chests, barrels, vases, pots, and corpses"](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6457499/6457499#items).

Comment: Acts 3 and 4 have different drop-rates, so which is it?  Act 3 or act 4?  Or somewhere in-between *(in which case, it's not really the same as either...)*?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Edited to clarify. Inferno act 3/4 have the same drop rates, all other difficulties don't, and whimsyshire goes based on act 4.

Comment: Personally, I have yet to get a single drop in any part of Hell that is either ilvl 61 or 62 - I think it's bugged.

Comment: @fcrick I've found 2 blue's that were item level 61 in the ~2 hours of hell I played last night. So it works, they're just really low drop chance.